# Реализация запроса с анализом предыдущей строки

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Подскажите, есть ли в ClickHouse инструментарий по решению задачи с "островками сложности" в которых нужно определить новый остров всякий раз, когда выполняется условие, сравнивающее какой-то элемент из текущей строки с элементом из предыдущей.

[Реализация на TSQL](https://www.osp.ru/winitpro/2017/10/13053489/)

Собственно интересует наличие аналогов функций (в документации таких не нашел)

- LAG()
- OVER PARTITION

Про реализацию подзапросов прочитал - ClickHouse не про это, но может быть можно как-то по другому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полноценных оконных функций нет. Есть кое-какие функции, которые позволяют использовать данные из соседних строк, например [runningDifference()](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/ru/single/#runningdifference-x), runningAccumulate (посчитать кумулятивное значение агрегатной функции).

Вот пример решения похожей задачи: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clickhouse/ZCZaMFEvoWw/7wn4PhTuDgAJ

Comment: Как Вы сами написали по ссылке, этот подход slightly ugly.
И немного не то, что я ищу. Тем не менее, спасибо за ответ.